# Cordova Android position fixed is not going well when the page scroll down

Tags: android, jquery, html, css, cordova

Please help me.. I don't know what to do anymore.. 
I'm working on android project now, I'm using cordova 3.5.
I made a swipeable menu, when I swipe to the left, the menu slide in from right, and when I swipe to right, the menu slide out to right.

The issue is I made this menu position fixed on css, It is going right when I first swipe the menu in and out.. But when I scroll the page.. The menu seems to go down and not fixed anymore.. how can I fixed it? I have tried to fix it for days.. but It still can't do right.. The strange things is, I'm using android 4.1 and it is not working well.. but when I try on android 4.4 KitKat It works well, even when I scroll the page down, the menu's not running away.. how can I make it works well on android 4.1 too? Thank you for your help..